# $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ are not isomorphic

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

How to prove that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ are not isomorphic. I thought that they are but I got this problem in Dummit Foote Section 14.1. Question no 4. As they extension over $\Bbb Q$ by the polynomials $x^2-2$ and $x^2-3$ resp.

Comment: Hint:  if $\phi: \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)\to \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ were an isomorphism, show that $\left(\phi(\sqrt 2)\right)^2=2$.  Derive a contradiction. Note:  I am assuming that you mean "isomorphic as extensions of $\mathbb Q$ but you should specify that.  As vector spaces over $\mathbb Q$, say, they are isomorphic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Take $\;w=a+b\sqrt2\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\;$ s.t. $\;\phi w=\sqrt3\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)\;$ , with $\;\phi\;$ an isomorphism. This means that

$$3=\phi w^2=\phi(a^2+2b^2+2ab\sqrt2)=a^2+2b^2+2ab\phi\sqrt2\implies\phi\sqrt2\in\Bbb Q$$

and now get a contradiction...

Comment: Gr8 thanks. My goodness, my mistake 